# Django deploy Heroku error 500 Debug = False

Tags: python, django, http, heroku, backend

Note: If `Debug = True` it runs just fine

Im trying to deply my django application

Main tools that im utilizing that i dont know if require a special configuration:
**Stripe (Payment Method - but its not in my index page so It shouldnt be because of it)
Mailgun(but i commented in my settings and im also not utilizing in Index page, so probably couldn't be it)**

Procfile

```
release: python3 manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn store.wsgi --preload --log-file –
```

My Env Variable setters:

```
from store.settings.base import *

env = environ.Env()

DEBUG = env.bool("DEUBG", False)

SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY")

DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db(),


}
```

My settings:

```
import django_on_heroku
import os
import environ
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['afternoon-brook-19806.herokuapp.com',
                 '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'templates/static']
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"  # BUG
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'


CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
PUBLISHED_KEY = 'pk_live_xxxxxxx'
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = 'sk_live_xxxxxxxxx?'
STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxx?'

django_on_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Where I get the error 500 in Heroku Logs:

```
2022-04-14T04:33:35.002535+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/account/login/" host=afternoon-brook-19806.herokuapp.com request_id=ac9b6df0-3598-427e-a672-9519419de8b3 fwd="177.124.150.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=68ms status=500 bytes=451 protocol=https
2022-04-14T04:33:35.003893+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.51.13 - - [14/Apr/2022:01:33:35 -0300] "GET /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://afternoon-brook-19806.herokuapp.com/account/register/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36"   
2022-04-14T04:33:38.997471+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.27.55 - - [14/Apr/2022:01:33:38 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; 
x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36"
2022-04-14T04:33:38.998359+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-brook-19806.herokuapp.com request_id=6d72ffac-e046-4315-a304-95f19cbe5d1c fwd="177.124.150.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=233ms status=500 bytes=451 protocol=https
2022-04-14T04:38:19.705332+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-brook-19806.herokuapp.com request_id=3bd4e671-70e3-45d3-a129-0445e40cac07 fwd="177.124.150.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=284ms status=500 bytes=451 protocol=https
2022-04-14T04:38:19.707351+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.85.250 - - [14/Apr/2022:01:38:19 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36"
2022-04-14T04:54:36.969390+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/account/register/" host=afternoon-brook-19806.herokuapp.com request_id=73c56c19-3f20-45b9-84a2-61cd1af2cbb5 fwd="44.201.124.202" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=500 bytes=451 protocol=https
2022-04-14T04:54:36.970932+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.35.168 - - [14/Apr/2022:01:54:36 -0300] "GET /account/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"2022-04-14T04:54:37.216540+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-brook-19806.herokuapp.com request_id=2bb68b8f-85a3-49a7-9a3c-3199023f1fcf fwd="44.201.124.202" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=236ms status=500 bytes=451 protocol=http
2022-04-14T04:54:37.217335+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.36.139 - - [14/Apr/2022:01:54:37 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
2022-04-14T04:55:04.990034+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/account/register/" host=afternoon-brook-19806.herokuapp.com request_id=699a6c8a-6c72-49be-985a-03b97425b0cf fwd="217.182.175.162" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=500 bytes=306 protocol=https
2022-04-14T04:55:04.992336+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.85.250 - - [14/Apr/2022:01:55:04 -0300] "HEAD /account/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36"
2022-04-14T04:57:02.924738+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/logout/" host=afternoon-brook-19806.herokuapp.com request_id=388154e3-ad25-4388-8d80-44cf8b33882c fwd="177.124.150.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=52ms status=200 bytes=2188 protocol=https
2022-04-14T04:57:02.926035+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.43.191 - - [14/Apr/2022:01:57:02 -0300] "GET /admin/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1629 "https://afternoon-brook-19806.herokuapp.com/admin/product/product/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36"
2022-04-14T04:57:05.345585+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.63.226 - - [14/Apr/2022:01:57:05 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36"
2022-04-14T04:57:05.345636+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-brook-19806.herokuapp.com request_id=8bfd526c-f4e2-45b5-be40-5edbac7514fb fwd="177.124.150.24" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=246ms status=500 bytes=451 protocol=https
```

Comment: did u forget to run `collectstatic` command?

Comment: i runnd git init, git add ., git commit -m "Name", heroku create, git push heroku master, and i set the variables, in the Procfile the migrations are autoapplied

Comment: As far as I guess, project static assets are not being rendered properly. , First, disable Heroku auto run of collectstatic , `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`, then manually run a command `python manage.py collectstatic` and then push the code to heroku.  More Info https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Comment: i did it, still it didnt work ;C , the commands: heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1,  python manage.py collectstatic, git add . , git commit -m Jamelaumn" , git push heroku master